# How can I know how much power can I generate?

Tags: power

Let's say we have a wind power of 6,831 megawatts. How can know how much power (i.e, megawatts/hour ) it can generate per year?

Comment: The unit of power is watt. It is not related to time. The watt-hour (or kWh, or MWh) is a unit of energy. You get it by multiplying the power with the duration. It is not clear from your question what that 6,831 MW is. Is it the energy in the wind, or the produced electrical energy? The fact that it is given in 4 significant digits gives me bad vibes. Wind energy is very variable, how can it be given so accurate?

Comment: Megawatts/hour measures the rate of change of power. In extreme weather, windspeeds may change rapidly, so megawatts/hour can be as much as the whole capacity (i.e. 6831 MW-hour in your example) for a wind installation. Over a wide area, it will usually be much lower as the wind won't start or stop everywhere at once.

Comment: **URGENT** George - you need to refine your question or it will be closed before you can discuss it. This will not stop people providing input but will make it harder for them to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *always* had 6831 megawatts, then this is how you would calculate how many megawatt-hours in a year:

```
6831 megawatts * 8765.81 hours = 59880546 megawatt hours
```

All you have to do is take the power multiplied by the time (the hours in a year in this case), and you get a number.

However, it's impossible to get exactly how much power you'll get in a year since wind power isn't constant. If it was a generator powered by natural gas, then that would be much more stable. You still couldn't get an exact number, but it'd be pretty close.

---

You seem to be looking at this the wrong way, thinking about this much harder than you have to. It seems as you're thinking that it will deplete a megawatt from the generator until it's replenished. *That's not true.* Let's look at what a megawatt equals.

A megawatt is a measurement of power. It's much bigger than a watt, but we'll look at the watt  first to simplify things. The equation for wattage: `wattage = voltage * amps`. You can then know that a light bulb that's 120 watts takes one amp, because common household AC voltage is 120V (in the US).

Well, what's a volt/amp? Voltage is similar to water pressure in a pipe, where amperage is how fast the water is flowing through the pipe.

*Well, how does the killowatt hour relate to this?* As far as I can tell, the killowatt hour is only used on your electric bill. Since you don't use the same amount of power 24/7, there needed to be a way to accurately bill you. (`watt-hour = watts * time used for`, or `watt-hour = amps used * 120V * time used for`)

Examples of the killowatt hour:

- *My fridge ran for five hours today, using 1A.* **Equation:** `120V * 1A * 5HR = 0.6 killowatt hours`
- *I had to charge my electric car today to go out to the store because my milk spoiled because I only had my fridge plugged in for five hours! It used 75A at 240V. It ran for three hours.* **Equation:** `240V * 75A * 3HR = 54 killowatt hours`

<sub>Note: 1000 killowatt hours is one megawatt hour.</sub>

Comment: Units are missing from the first example, that is bad practice ;) Also, how is "killowatt hours is to megawatt hours as millimeters is to centimeters"? The first is factor 1000, the latter factor 10. Further, how do you get to 8765.81 hours per year? And some of the analogies are totally off in my opinion :o "It's like saying that it's 350 degrees in the oven. When you put something cold in there, it's still going to be (around) 350 degrees." What?

Comment: @Rev1.0 The 8765.81 hours is adjusted for leap year... on second thought 8766 hours might be simpler. View edited answer.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin 8765 is a very nice figure to carry around in one's head, and more than accurate enough for any real world use. 8750 is not too bad either, for other reasons. And 8700 = 725 x 12 has summat to commend it.

Comment: Much better after the edits.

Answer (score 1):

Below is some information which may help. Please refine your question and ask more questions if desired. Don't worry if the question gets "closed" - people do that for all sorts of reasons. Just keep answering people's questions and refining you original question and we should be able to help you.

6831 is a very specific amount of power and it is not obvious where it comes from.
Why did you choose that figure.

What you probably need are Weibull distribution curves for a given site that plot speed against probability of occurrence for a given site.

Some sites are very peaky in wind speed with few speeds above or below a normal range.
Others may taper downwards with speed  or up or have two peaks or ...

[Pictures to guide](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=weibull+wind&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=5sjTU4bQBdTq8AWRqYCwAQ&ved=0CCUQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=826)

Wind Power Program . com

- [Wind statistics and the Weibull distribution.](http://www.wind-power-program.com/wind_statistics.htm)
- [Estimating mean wind speed](http://www.wind-power-program.com/windestimates.htm)

[Penn state video - 4 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=To4-NWsNwnA) <- **Useful**

[Swiss wind power data website - Weibull calculator](http://wind-data.ch/tools/weibull.php?lng=en)

[Wikipedia - Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution)